# When removing appbar makes a gap between next two widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

when the appBar remove or make it null there is a gap problem between the next 2 widgets

when i remove appBar from the code the gap between next 2 widgets get's bigger

```dart
appBar : AppBar()
body: Container (
   child : Column (
     children [
        child : ListTile(....)
        Expanded(
          childe: ListView(
             children : List.generats(5, (index) =>
             child : ListTile(...)
```

Comment: Which 2 widgets? ListTile and ListView?

Comment: that's the program and when i remove the appbar there will be a big gap between first listtile and the next listview